# DBInit DatabaseTablesPreparer NullPointerException

Tags: database, orm, intershop

We are trying to execute DatabaseTablesPreparer dbinit proces on Intershop 7.9 to create custom objects in the database. The process for that preparer fails with the following exception:

```
ES1 dbinit [] [app_core_a1:Class1 DatabaseTablesPreparer Version:null] com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit [] [] [] [] "main" Error executing app_core_a1:Class1 DatabaseTablesPreparer Version:null java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:112)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.dbinit.preparer.database.DatabaseTablesPreparer.mergeEnfinityTable(DatabaseTablesPreparer.java:159)
```

We have decompiled the preparer, and it seems that the following method returns null:

```
protected Cartridge getCartridge()
  {
    if (this.cartridge == null)
    {
      String cartridgeName = System.getProperty("intershop.CurrentCartridgeName");
      this.cartridge = this.cartridgeMgr.getCartridge(cartridgeName);
    }
    return this.cartridge;
  }
```

Should the cartridge name be explicitly defined somewhere?

EDIT #1:

Full error log:

```
ES1 dbinit [] [] com.intershop.platform.cartridge.internal.CartridgeImpl [] [] [] [] "main" Neither Ivy descriptor nor cartridge properties found for cartridge 'app_core_a1'! 
ES1 dbinit [] [] com.intershop.platform.cartridge.internal.CartridgeImpl [] [] [] [] "main" Neither Ivy descriptor nor cartridge properties found for cartridge 'init_a1_shop'! 
ES1 dbinit [] [app_core_a1:Class1 DatabaseTablesPreparer Version:null] com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit [] [] [] [] "main" Error executing app_core_a1:Class1 DatabaseTablesPreparer Version:null java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:112)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.dbinit.preparer.database.DatabaseTablesPreparer.mergeEnfinityTable(DatabaseTablesPreparer.java:159)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.dbinit.preparer.database.DatabaseTablesPreparer.migrateEnfinityTable(DatabaseTablesPreparer.java:126)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.dbinit.preparer.database.DatabaseTablesPreparer.migrateBeanTables(DatabaseTablesPreparer.java:92)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.dbinit.preparer.database.DatabaseTablesPreparer.migrateBeanTables(DatabaseTablesPreparer.java:71)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.dbinit.preparer.database.DatabaseTablesPreparer.prepare(DatabaseTablesPreparer.java:53)
    at com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit.execute(DBInit.java:347)
    at com.intershop.tool.common.PreparerUtils.execute(PreparerUtils.java:271)
    at com.intershop.tool.common.PreparerUtils.executePreparers(PreparerUtils.java:232)
    at com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit.prepareCartridge(DBInit.java:522)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.cartridge.Cartridge.onDBInit(Cartridge.java:595)
    at com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit.execute(DBInit.java:445)
    at com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit.run(DBInit.java:598)
    at com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit.main(DBInit.java:133)
```

dbinit.properties:

```
#
# Database Tables Preparer, implicit added by DBInit as pre.Class1
Class1 = com.intershop.beehive.core.dbinit.preparer.database.DatabaseTablesPreparer

#
# Indexes
Class2  = com.intershop.beehive.core.dbinit.preparer.database.DatabaseIndexesPreparer \
          resources/main/hr/a1/core/dbinit/scripts/dbindex.ddl

#
# Constraints
Class3  = com.intershop.beehive.core.dbinit.preparer.database.DatabaseConstraintsPreparer \
          resources/main/hr/a1/core/dbinit/scripts/dbconstraints.ddl
```

Dbinit command:

```
dbinit.bat --exec-id=app_core_a1:Class1
```

Comment: No it should know in which cartridge it is running. Can you post the dbinit properties and command you use to run dbinit?

Comment: Can you check your dbinit error log for a message like 'Neither Ivy descriptor nor cartridge properties found for cartridge ...'? The version can be NULL too if the properties or ivy parsing fails for any reason.

Comment: @WillemEvertse I edited the original post, you can find it there.

Comment: @Konrad Yes, I can see that message in the error log, I have edited the original post with the full error log. How can it be fixed?

Comment: So Konrad was right. Is your cartridge building?

Comment: @WillemEvertse yes, Konrad was right. I have added the cartridge.properties file and the preparer finishes successfully without any errors now and the table is created in the DB. Thanks for help guys.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by adding [cartridge].properties file for the cartridge which dbinit was being ran for. Once the .properties file is added preparer finishes succesfully and the table is created in the DB.